# Join two tables together in Ruby/Rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm new to Rails and I'm not sure how to do this:

I'm writing a rake script that needs to reference off of a value from two tables:
The owner_id in the Animals table references the Owner table:

```
Animals:[
 {id:1, name:"Bow wow", owner_id:1, score:null}, 
 {id:2, name:"Chiaow", owner_id:2, score:null}, 
 {id:3, name:"Fishbob and Ben", owner_id:9, score:null}
]

Owner:[
  {id:1, name:"Doug"}, 
  {id:2, name:"Michelle"}, 
  {id:9, name:"Ben"}
]
```

I would like to combine both these tables to get a result that looks like this:

```
Combined = [
  {id:1, score:null, keywords:"Bow Wow Doug", name:"Bow wow", owner:"Doug"}, 
  {id:2, score:null, keywords:"Chiaow Michelle", name:"Chiaow, owner:Michelle",
  {id:3, score:null, keywords:"Fishbob and Ben", name:"Fishbob", owner:"Ben"}
]
```

I want to also index through the keywords using

```
  combined_list = Combined.where("keywords LIKE (?)", "%#{chosen_word}%")
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join two models (Animal and Owner) you can select which attributes from the joined table you want to make available in the instances:

```rb
combined = Animal.joins(:owner).select(:id, :name, 'owners.name as owner_name')
puts combined.first.name, combined.first.owner_name
```

This implies of course, that the Animal model `belongs_to :owner`.

To filter this relation I would do this:

```rb
cw = "%#{chosen_word}%"
combined.where('animals.name LIKE ?', cw).
         or(combined.where('owners.name LIKE ?', cw))
```

Comment: I think it should be owners.name
`combined = Animal.joins(:owner).select(:id, :name, 'owners.name as owner_name')`